# Установка Yii2 проблема с composer

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii2, composer

os Ubuntu

composer установлен глобально

ввожу(в папке под проект):

composer create-project --prefer-dist --stability=dev vova07/yii2-start yii2-start

выдает сообщение

[InvalidArgumentException]
  Composer could not find a composer.json file in /home/chupakabra/my_www/vhost1/composer_test/2/yii2
  To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.or
  g/ "Getting Started" section

инструкция взята отсюда https://github.com/vova07/yii2-start

Comment: у меня эта строчка нормально отработала, может вы делаете не совсем то, что пишите? даже если прав на запись нет, то сообщение другим будет. Правда "нормально" - без вашего сообщения, у меня там другие проблемы: *yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.*

Answer (score 2):

Если не ошибаюсь попробуй перед выполнением написать self-update или composer self-update